# Unable to Split the string accordingly

Tags: c#, arrays, string, delimiter

I know this question would have been asked infinite number of times, but I'm kinda stuck.
I have a string something like

> "Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;12"

it can be something like

> "Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;Doc4;Doc5;56"

Its like few pieces of strings separated by semicolon, followed by a number or id.

I need to extract the number/id and the strings separately.
To be exact, I can have 2 strings: one having `"Doc1;Doc2;Doc3"` or `"Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;Doc4"` and the other having just the number/id as "12" or "34" or "45" etc.
And yeah I am using C# 3.5

I understand its a pretty easy and witty question, but this guy is stuck.
Assistance required from experts.

Regards
Anurag

Comment: `var leList = yourString.Split(';').ToList()` and in last element you have ID -> `var id = leList.Last()`

Comment: What means "I can have 2 strings"? As desired result or as input?

Comment: @TimSchmelter desired input

Comment: @user1638283, since the post has been solved, please **accept an answer.** You can do that by clicking the little gray check mark that's underneath of the voting area on each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string actual = "Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;12";
int lstindex = actual.LastIndexOf(';');
string strvalue = actual.Substring(0, lstindex);
string id = actual.Substring(lstindex + 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

[string.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.LastIndexOf.aspx) and [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) are the keys to what you're trying to do.

```
var str = "Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;12";
var ind = str.LastIndexOf(';');
var str1 = str.Substring(0, ind);
var str2 = str.Substring(ind+1);
```

Comment: +1, that combination would work as long the pattern was always what the OP gave as an example. However, please provide a code example for the OP, you've got 12k rep, you know that a code example is what makes a good answer.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I was editing in an example as you wrote your comment - I was short on time, thought I should get the first part in there first. :)

Comment: @user1638283 Glad I could help! On StackOverflow, accepting an answer is the proper way to mark your problem as "Solved". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and/or http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(';');
var docs = tokens.Where(s => s.StartsWith("Doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
var numbers = tokens.Where(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tim...it helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
String docs = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(';'));
String number = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(';') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanku for the answer

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be this:

```
var ids = new List<string>();
var nums = new List<string>();

foreach (var s in input.Split(';'))
{
    int val;
    if (!int.TryParse(s, out val)) { ids.Add(s); }
    else { nums.Add(s); }
}
```

where `input` is something like `Doc1;Doc2;Doc3;Doc4;Doc5;56`. Now, `ids` will house all of the `Doc1` like values and `nums` will house all of the `56` like values.

Answer (score 2):

You may try one of two options: (assuming your input string is in `string str;`

Approach 1

1. Get `LastIndexOf(';')`
2. Split the `string` based on the `index`. This will give you `string` and `int` part.
3. Split the `string` part and process it
4. Process the `int` part

Approach 2

1. Split the string on `;`
2. Run a `for` loop - `for (int i = 0; i < str.length - 2; i++)` - this is the `string` part
3. Process str[length - 1] separately - this is the `int` part

> Please take this as a starting point as there could be other approaches to implement a solution for this

Answer (score 2):

you can use StringTokenizer functionality.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pseabury/JavaLikeStringTokenizer11232005015829AM/JavaLikeStringTokenizer.aspx

split string using ";"
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(src1,";");

collect final String. that will be your ID.